# IIS7: Unable to read CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, iis-7

I am unble to read csv file when I use URl of the Website. But, it runs fine when I run using VS2010. I know it is permission issue: as I am new to server side I need some help. All other Webpages that don't deal with CSV file are running fine. I am using IIS7. Till now I have played with DCOM, WMI and have given access to everyone. There is no error Website is not able to open the file and read it.

Please let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: Is this a programming question...? Can you show your code and the error produced?

Comment: No Robnick, this is clearly permission issue. I am not getting any error but webpage just times out as it is not able to access the excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works: Click on the site name. Double click Authentication. Select ASPNET Impersonation.Click Select the user and enter your credentials similarly select the sever and follow above instruction for ASP.NET Impersonation. And it will work!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure IUSR has read permissions for the directory that contains the csv file.

Comment: Hi Jamie , I will try this.  Is there anything I need to add for WMI? have added object name "Everyone". But did not work?

Comment: I tried to read a file on the win 2008 server itself: also added IUSR full control but still cannot read the file.

Comment: It has been my experience that adding the permissions stated above fixes the issue.  Are you getting an exception?  If so, what is the message?  Perhaps your browser is suppressing error messages.  Off the top of my head I am unable to think of a case where the failure to load a file would not result in some type of exception.